# What is the difference between "remember" and "mutableState" in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new in jetpack compose and trying to understand the difference between `remember` and `mutableStateOf`

In other words the deference between this line

```
val text = remember{ mutableStateOf("") }
```

and this

```
val text = remember{ "" }
```

and this also

```
val text = mutableStateOf("")
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`remember` is a composable function that can be used to cache expensive operations. You can think of it as a cache which is local to your composable.

```kotlin
val state: Int = remember { 1 }
```

The `state` in the above code is immutable. If you want to change that state and also update the UI, you can use a `MutableState`. `Compose` will observe any reads/writes the `MutableState` object and trigger a [recomposition](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#composition-and-recomposition) to update the UI.

```kotlin
val state: MutableState<Int> = remember { mutableStateOf(1) }

Text(
   modifier = Modifier.clickable { state.value += 1 },
   text = "${state.value}",
 )
```

Another variant (added in `alpha12`) called `rememberSaveable` which is similar to `remember`, but the stored value can survive process death or configuration changes.

```
val state: MutableState<Int> = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(1) }
```

**Note**: You can also use property delegates as a syntactic sugar to unwrap the `MutableState`.

```
var state: Int by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
```

Regarding the last part of your question:

> ```
> val text = mutableStateOf("")
> ```

<s>`MutableState` is an alternative to using `LiveData` or `Flow`. `Compose` does not observe any changes to this object by default and therefore no recomposition will happen. If you want the changes to be observed and the state to be cached use `remember`. If you don't need the caching but only want to observe, you can use `derivedStateOf`. Here is a [sample](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1434397/5/compose/runtime/runtime/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/runtime/samples/EffectSamples.kt#131) of how to use it.</s>

As pointed out by [Ahmad Hamwi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11973979/ahmad-hamwi) in the comments and quoting them:

> Compose does observe the value of the state, in fact there's a @Stable annotation on top of it, and that's its sole responsibility, but since we're not remembering the state, a mutableStateOf(1) will always be created AGAIN, so there will be a new instance of a state, but will still have the same value of 1. So the state seems to not change, but there IS a recomposition happening.

Comment: Can you kindly check the question edits? @ckunder

Comment: @AhmedM.Abdalla I have updated my answer.

Comment: @ckunder quoting you in the last part of your answer "Compose does not observe any changes to this object by default and therefore no recomposition will happen". Compose does observe the value of the state, in fact there's a ```@Stable``` annotation on top of it, and that's its sole responsibility, but since we're not remembering the state, a ```mutableStateOf(1)``` will always be created AGAIN, so there will be a new instance of a state, but will still have the same value of 1. So the state seems to not change, but there IS a recomposition happening.

Comment: rememer has nothing to do with observing the data

Comment: So... maybe a dumb question, but what's the point of `mutableStateOf`? Seems like every time we use it we would always pair it with `remember`. Why would I use it alone?

Comment: It doesn't have to save strictly expensive operations, but rather any state you want reassigned during recomposition (Unless it gets assigned a new value inside a conditional block).

Answer (score 22):

As i understand.

`remember` just **cache result** of computation to **keep result instance between compositions**. Any object. And `MutableState` instance. And this is why it is useful.

```
val text = remember{ "" }
```

just cache empty string.

```
val text = mutableStateOf("")
```

create `MutableState` and `compose` observe it value, but not cache `MutableState` instance, so it will be re-created on next recomposition (of course if recomposition will happen in this place)

for example:

```
val state: MutableState<Int> =  mutableStateOf(1)
println(state.toString())
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.clickable { state.value += 1 },
    text = "${state.value}",
)
```

the text will always be 1, because every recomposition re-creates `state` and the output will be:

```
MutableState(value=1)@227069120
MutableState(value=1)@104526071
MutableState(value=1)@915621104
MutableState(value=1)@580489706
```

`remember` caches `MutableState` object and keep same instance on every recomposition

```
val state: MutableState<Int> = remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
println(state.toString())
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.clickable { state.value += 1 },
    text = "${state.value}",
)
```

work as expected.

```
MutableState(value=2)@1121832406
MutableState(value=3)@1121832406
MutableState(value=4)@1121832406
MutableState(value=5)@1121832406
```

**remember(key)**

```
val key = remember { 0 }
var state by remember(key) { mutableStateOf(1) }
println(state.toString())
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.clickable { state += 1 },
    text = "${state}",
)
```

Works like the example above, even though the `key` doesn't change. It's because in case of a `MutableState`, not the value is cached, but the instance of `MutableState` itself with the `value` field, which changes.

changing `key` value will recreate `MutableState` instance

Comment: This answer gives the root cause: keep the state data when the fun is repeatedly called, or it will be repeatedly initialized.

Answer (score 13):

If `remember` is used with a field it's value will persist across recompositions.

If `mutableState` is used with a field, all the composables which are using that field will be recomposed whenever the field values changes.

Answer (score 8):

**mutableStateOf():** it's an observable that observes the values when underlaying values gets changes and updates the UI. like we use *liveData* and *stateFlows* but LiveData also has lifecycle mechanism and almost same goes with StateFlows. 
**remember{}:** It persists the data across the recomposition.
what is recomposition? When the state get changes, the composable that holds that value recomposes itself to give us updated value.
**for example:** *we have a textView(composable) that observes the value, right now which is **1**. We press the button and increment the value with **2**. What happens here when the value goes from 1 to 2 the textView(composable) recreates(**recomposes**) itself and shows us the updated value which is **2**, this is known as recomposition.*

when we use this: `val text = remember{ mutableStateOf("") }` that's means we are not only observing the data but also persisting the data across the recomposition.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, in the first example you are storing a mutable value and in the second you are storing an immutable value.

According to the doc: "You can store immutable values when caching expensive UI operations, such as computing text formatting. The remembered value is stored in the Composition with the composable that called remember." [Source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-remember-to-store-immutable-values)

For more info on mutableStateOf, here is the doc [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-rememeber-to-create-internal-state-in-composable). You use this when you want your UI the be recomposed when there is a change in your values.

Answer (score 2):

The remember keyword can store a mutable or an immutable object. If you pass mutableStateOf to remember, any time the value of that object changes, it will force recomposition of the composables that are reading that value.