# how to set value to a remember val and not recompose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Blow the code, I want to set value to currentDegree on animate end, but when I do it, it recomposes. How to make it not recompose?

```
    @Composable
    fun RotateImageCompose(width: Dp, height: Dp, resId: Int, targetDegree: Float) {
        val currentDegree = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

        var diff = currentDegree.value - targetDegree
        .
        .
        .

        val dregree by animateFloatAsState(targetValue = diff, animationSpec = tween(
            easing = LinearEasing,
            durationMillis = 180
        ), finishedListener = {
            //this code cause the issue
            currentDegree.value = it
        })

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = resId),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .rotate(dregree)
                .size(width, height)
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I save the value outside the compose

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

```
val currentDegree = remember {0f}
```

That way your value is immutable.

Please look here for a detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66178263/5513788

Comment: In your way, currentDegree is always 0f. But I need change it and remember it but not trigger recompose