# How to do work off the main thread in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

In a Jetpack Compose app I have a LazyVerticalGrid of thumbnails, each of which needs to be drawn in a bitmap-backed Canvas at compose time.

The thumbnails draw correctly if I simply draw them in DrawScope of the Canvas, but the user experience is poor. When the user scrolls the LazyVerticalGrid, there is a lot of jank as each thumbnail draws itself.

I had thought that Jetpack Compose composed in background threads when needed, but it all seems to be happening on the main thread, leading to the severe jank, even on the latest phones.

I can solve the jank problem by drawing onto the Canvas's underlying bitmap on another thread, using LaunchedEffect withContext(IO). But the problem is, Compose doesn't know to recompose the Canvas when the bitmap is drawn, so I often end up with half-drawn thumbnails.

Is there a way to do work off the main thread and then recompose once that work is done?

Here is the janky code (edited for brevity), followed by the non-janky version that doesn't always recompose when the drawing is complete:

```
   val imageBitmap = remember {Bitmap.createBitmap(515, 618, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)}
   val bitmapCanvas = remember { android.graphics.Canvas(imageBitmap) }
   ElevatedCard() {
      Canvas() {
         bitmapCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
         penStrokes.forEach {
           inker.drawEvent(it)
         }
         this.drawImage(imageBitmap.asImageBitmap())
       }
   }
```

non-janky but still not right

```
   val imageBitmap = remember {Bitmap.createBitmap(515, 618, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)}
   val bitmapCanvas = remember { android.graphics.Canvas(imageBitmap) }
   LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
      withContext(IO) {
         bitmapCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
         penStrokes.forEach {
           inker.drawEvent(it)
         }
      }
   }
   ElevatedCard() {
      Canvas() {
         this.drawImage(imageBitmap.asImageBitmap())
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I used the common "invalidate++" kludge that people seem to use to force Jetpack Compose to redraw on command. It has a bit of code smell to it, I think, but it does the trick.

```
val imageBitmap = remember {Bitmap.createBitmap(515, 618, 
     Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)}
val bitmapCanvas = remember { android.graphics.Canvas(imageBitmap) }
var invalidate by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }


LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
  withContext(IO) {
     bitmapCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
     penStrokes.forEach {
       inker.drawEvent(it)
     }
     invalidate++
  }
}

ElevatedCard() {
   Canvas() {
      invalidate.let {
           this.drawImage(imageBitmap.asImageBitmap())
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Is `penStrokes` a `SnapshotStateList`?

Jetpack Compose can only reliably update when the dependencies are [`StateObject`s](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/snapshots/StateObject). Mutable objects that aren't optimized for Compose are not [`@Stable`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/stability), which means every time a composable is recomposed, all children composable with unstable dependencies will get recomposed as well, impacting performance. The same is true not only for composition but for other [phases](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/phases) as well, such as [drawing](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/phases#phase3-drawing), which is the phase the `Canvas` block is run on, where the OP is drawing on the bitmap.

You should make `penStrokes` a [`SnapshotStateList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/snapshots/SnapshotStateList) by constructing it with [`mutableStateListOf()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateListOf()). `SnapshotList`s are `StateObject`s, so they will play nicely with the [`Snapshot`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/snapshots/Snapshot) system.

## Offloading drawing to a background thread

To do so, we need a way to listen to changes in `penStrokes` without triggering recomposition. That's what [`snapshotFlow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#snapshotFlow(kotlin.Function0)) is for — it takes a block which is run inside a snapshot, and every time any of its dependencies change, it is run again, and the results of that block over time are emitted to the [`Flow`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/) that is returned. `snapshotFlow` can effectively be used to turn a Compose `State` into a Coroutines `Flow`, such as in:

```
var myState by remember { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    val flow = snapshotFlow { myState }
}
```

However, that works for changing values, not for interior mutability. Since we're using a `SnapshotList`, it would only work if the `snapshotFlow` block actually read something from or iterated over the list. A dumb fix would be having `snapshotFlow { myList.toList() }`, where `.toList()` actually makes an immutable copy of the `myList` at that point in time, and since it involves iterating over the list, the snapshot system correctly registers it and the returned `Flow` would iterate over immutable snapshots of the `myList`. However, a more efficient solution would be to simply do the work inside the `snapshotFlow` block, even ignoring the returned `Flow`.

```
var penStrokes by remember { mutableStateListOf<PenStroke>() }

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        snapshotFlow {
            bitmapCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
            penStrokes.forEach { stroke ->
                inker.drawEvent(stroke)
            }
            invalidate++
        }
    }
}
```

It is true that since we're mutating a `Bitmap`, which is not a `StateObject`, we need the aid of a counter to trigger invalidations, just like the OP [@John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3947344/john) has shown in [their own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74871166/8154765).

## Hardware acceleration

However, note that drawing on a `Bitmap` is not hardware-accelerated, incurring in a significant performance cost. That's why we need to offload drawing to a background thread in the first place. To draw more efficiently, on Android a [`SurfaceView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) could be used, which can be embedded in Compose using the [`AndroidView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/viewinterop/package-summary) composable. Then [`Surface.lockHardwareCanvas()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface#lockHardwareCanvas()) would obtain a `Canvas` that is also hardware-accelerated. From Android 14 onwards, [`HardwareBufferRenderer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/HardwareBufferRenderer) can be used as well to reduce latency in that it's zero-copy and the contents are preserved across renders, opening up the possibility of drawing new strokes without redrawing the previous ones on every frame.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken then Compose does not redraw when you change the *contents* of the bitmap only. Changing contents of a *remember* object does not trigger a redraw or rendering.

Maybe this helps:
[What is the difference between "remember" and "mutableState" in android jetpack compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66169601/what-is-the-difference-between-remember-and-mutablestate-in-android-jetpack)